# Change title on html with setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm trying to set an effect to the title of my page, that it appear letter by letter but I can't understand why does `setInterval()` function didn't work.

Here is the code I tried.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var namee=document.title
var i=0
function changeTit(){
    document.title=namee.substring(0,i)
    i++
    if(i>namee.length)
        i=0
}
setInterval(changeTit(),1000)
</script>
```

This is running the `changeTit()` function only one time, i also tried to call it in a button but one letter appear every time I hit the button and I want it to be changing all the time.
This code is in the head section but i also tryed in several different parts of the document, please tell if this gotta be in some specific part, I also tried separating in different sections.

Comment: You're semicolon key seems broken^^ You should better add them yourself instead of relying on the interpreter to do this job in your mind

Comment: You shouldn't use that obtrusive code. Maybe when someone which has your page in a tab but is currently viewing another tab, wants to switch to yours but the title is empty and can't find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
setInterval(changeTit(),1000)
```

To:

```
setInterval(changeTit, 1000)
```

So by removing `()`, you make sure that you pass the **actual function** rather than passing the **result** (of calling) of that function to `setInterval`

Comment: Good answer, it is worth mentioning that javascript functions are first class objects which is why you can pass them around. setInterval calls the first parameter (changeTit) after the given amount of miliseconds have passed